# Modx EVO как устранить конфликт TinyMCE c Bootstrap и Colorbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, modx, tinymce

MODX EVO 1.4.0.RC2: если выводить TinyMCE4 в модальном окне (через Colorbox) не работает редактирование исходного кода, вставки ссылок и пр.
Код в плагине TinyMCE4

```
// For displaying modals inside external lightboxes
    jQuery(document).on('focusin.bs.modal', function(e) { if (jQuery(e.target).closest(".mce-window").length && jQuery('#colorbox').is(":visible")) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); }})
```

должен решать эту проблему, но не решает.
`jQuery.noConflict();` тоже не помогает. В консоли ошибок нет. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо при инициализации colorbox добавить trapFocus: false.